# CVS to Mercurial conversion with CRLF

Tags: mercurial, cvs, eol, mercurial-convert

I have converted a CVS repository to Mercurial, but the carriage returns are converted from CRLF (Windows style) to LF (Unix style). However, I want CRLFs in the repository! I realise that you can [combat this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754281/cvs-to-mercurial-conversion-end-of-line-problem) with Mercurial extensions win32text and eol. But I would really prefer to have the repository converted with CRLFs in the first place.

I would like to hear if anyone has succeeded in this endeavour!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrm, I've not heard people say it does that before, but I've never tried to put CRLF in a repo before either.  I'd guess it's not the mercurial convert doing the line ending change so much as it's the cvs export tool that it chains off to.  I

Try using cvs2svn or cvs2git as an intermediary step as recommended here: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryConversion#CVS